# Spring AMQP Rabbit MQ Transaction exception during commit

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm trying to use Spring to write a transactional message to a HA RabbitMQ cluster and also write an entity into a H2 database in a single transaction.

My code works for the standard case, the problem I have is caused when testing error scenarios. If I disconnect the network cable of the rabbit node the program is connected to, an exception is thrown during the commit phase, which I would expect to rollback, but the message is somehow written to the rabbit queue and my entity is persisted to the database?

Here is the exception I am receiving:

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: failed to commit RabbitMQ transaction
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitResourceHolder.commitAll(RabbitResourceHolder.java:154)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$RabbitResourceSynchronization.processResourceAfterCommit(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:256)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$RabbitResourceSynchronization.processResourceAfterCommit(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:236)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolderSynchronization.afterCommit(ResourceHolderSynchronization.java:85)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:133)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:121)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:954)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:799)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:515)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.sendMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.transactional.RabbitSender.run(RabbitSender.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.txCommit(ChannelN.java:1163)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.txCommit(ChannelN.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:704)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.txCommit(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitResourceHolder.commitAll(RabbitResourceHolder.java:151)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:361)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:226)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:290)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:536)
```

This is my code sending the message and writing the database entity: 
(This is called repeately in a loop up to X messages. The loop **does not attempt to resend messages** if it receives an exception )

```java
@Service
public class SenderServiceImpl implements SenderService {

   private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SenderServiceImpl.class);   

   private DatabaseService databaseService;

   private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

   private RabbitTemplate template;

   private AtomicLong messageId;

   private final String startTime;   

   private final String exchange;

   private final String routingKey;

   @Autowired
   public SenderServiceImpl( DatabaseService databaseService,
                             ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, 
                             @Value("${rabbitmq.exchange}") String exchange, 
                             @Value("${rabbitmq.routingKey}") String routingKey) {
      this.databaseService = databaseService;
      this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
      this.exchange   = exchange;
      this.routingKey = routingKey;
      this.startTime  = "" + new Date().getTime();
      this.messageId  = new AtomicLong(0);
   }

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
      template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
      template.setChannelTransacted( true );
   }

   @Transactional(rollbackFor=AmqpException.class) 
   public void sendMessage( String messageString ) throws AmqpException {   
      String messageCorrelationId = startTime + "-" + messageId.incrementAndGet();

      MessageProperties properties = new MessageProperties();      
      properties.setMessageId( messageCorrelationId );      

      Message message = new Message(messageString.getBytes(), properties );      

      template.send( exchange, routingKey, message, new CorrelationData( messageCorrelationId ) );
      databaseService.saveMessage( messageString, messageCorrelationId );
   }
}
```

To provide complete information here is my DatabaseService implementation

```java
@Service
public class DatabaseServiceImpl implements DatabaseService {

   private TestDao testDao;

   @Autowired
   public DatabaseServiceImpl( TestDao testDao ) {
      this.testDao = testDao;      
   }

   @Override
   @Transactional
   public void saveMessage( String message, String messageId ) {
      testDao.saveMessage( message, messageId );      
   }
}
```

and TestDao class

```java
@Repository
public class TestDao {

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager entityManager;

   public void saveMessage( String message, String messageId ) {
      TestEntity entity = new TestEntity();
      entity.setMessage( message );
      entity.setMessageId( messageId );
      entityManager.persist( entity );    
   }    
}
```

And my applicationContext.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit" 
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

   <!-- Configuration for Component Scan -->
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.transactional" />

   <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:rabbitmq.properties" />

   <!-- RabbitMQ Connection Factory -->
   <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" 
                              addresses="${rabbitmq.addresses}" 
                              username="${rabbitmq.username}"
                              password="${rabbitmq.password}" />


   <!-- Transaction Manager-->   
   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- JPA Adapter -->
   <bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
      <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.H2Platform" />
      <property name="showSql" value="true" />        
   </bean>  

   <!-- EntityManager -->
   <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
      <property name="persistenceUnitName"    value="TestPU" />      
      <property name="loadTimeWeaver"> 
         <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
      </property>
      <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
         <map>
            <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
         </map>
      </property>
   </bean>

   <!-- This instructs spring to check for the @Transactional annotation -->
   <tx:annotation-driven />

   <!-- bean post-processor for JPA annotations -->
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

This test application connects to the RabbitMQ, via a HAProxy server. The cluster is configured with 3 rabbit nodes.

Just to recap the problem. If I try to send 30,000 messages, and I pull the network cable from the rabbit node I am connected to. The application will throw several AmqpExceptions during the 20 seconds or so HAProxy takes to notice the server is down.

The application will not attempt to resend any failed messages, but my receiving application will receive the full 30,000 messages, and my database will contain the full 30000 entities?

Can anyone help me figure out why?

### Update

To try and clarify further here is the test function that loops blindly trying to send messages regardless of success.

```java
for(int i = 0; i < MESSAGE_LIMIT; i++) {                  
     try {
         senderService.sendMessage( "Message:" + i );
     } catch (Throwable th) {
         LOG.error("Unable to send message.", th);
     }   
}
```

As an example of the setup for the test, the initial state has the sending application connected via HAProxy to Rabbit Node 1.

[Initial State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaHEG.png)

Then we cut off the network connection to Rabbit Node 1 from HAProxy. HAProxy takes about 20 seconds before realising it cannot connect to Rabbit Node one. During this time the AmqpException arises - I would expect these transactions to roll back.

[State after cutting connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SePYs.png)

After the 20 seconds HAProxy sends connections to one of the remaining 2 rabbit nodes and the process continues as normal.

Comment: Sorry, it isn't clear by your explanation if it is an issue only in case of HA, or you have the same even only with the single RabbitMQ node. I guess you should have the same issue even with the raw Spring AMQP. I mean there is no involve JPA to reproduce. Would you mind confirming ?

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan, Yes this is only an issue in the case of HA.

If I run the same test (still connected via HAProxy) using a single rabbit node I get an `org.springframework.amqp.AmqpTimeoutException` or a `org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException` and the transaction is rolled back. The message is not delivered to rabbit and is not persisted to the database - as you would expect.

I'm going to add an update to my question to attempt to clarify further the scenario .... it's quite difficult to describe precisely!